Escape Block Textures Not Loading After Leaving First Room
Godot Version: v4.2.stable.official [46dc27791]
I am trying to have an escape block with a TextureRect that has two different textures--an animated one where it's awake and an inanimate one where it's asleep. The textures for my escape blocks display properly on the first room (only if the player just started--no changing scenes beforehand) and appear as a blank white texture other times (i.e. when leaving and reentering the scene). I have tried rewriting my code and using different methods and nodes to swap out the escape block textures, but all of them result in the white texture appearing at least some of the time.
I have tried rewriting my code and using different methods and nodes to swap out the escape block textures, but all of them result in the white texture appearing at least some of the time.
When I changed the wake and sleep functions to something simple (albeit not desired):
func wake():
  modulate.a = 1
  texture.set_pause(false)

The textures still fail to load. Looks like it has nothing to do with the code failing to swap out the sprites, but rather the textures themselves not loading.
I also tried rewriting the escape block code to use the wake and sleep textures directly rather than applying them to a single texture:
func wake():
    wake_rect.visible = true
    sleep_rect.visible = false
    modulate.a = 1

(Small snippet shown for convenience - full escape block code is on the pastebin I linked)
Still not working.
Can anyone help me figure out what I'm doing wrong or link me to an answer for reference? I’ve looked around but couldn't find anything.

Here's my code for the escape blocks.
Here's a screenshots of my scene dock showing Escape Block:
Here's a short video I uploaded of my running game.


I FINALLY FIXED IT LET'S GOOOOOOOOOOOO
I saved both the awake and asleep textures as .tres files and rewrote the code to have a single TextureRect use the .tres files:
extends StaticBody2D

var shape
var awake
var done = false
var temp_texture: Texture2D

@export var reverse = false # Reverse = sleep before panic, wake afterwards

@onready var collision_shape = $CollisionShape2D

@onready var texture_rect = $BlockTexture
@onready var texture = $BlockTexture.texture

const ESCAPE_BLOCK_AWAKE = preload("res://texture/escape_block_awake.tres")

const ESCAPE_BLOCK_SLEEP = preload("res://texture/escape_block_sleep.tres")

func wake():
    texture_rect.texture = ESCAPE_BLOCK_AWAKE
    modulate.a = 1
    set_collision_layer_value(1, true)
    set_collision_layer_value(2, true)
    set_collision_layer_value(3, true)
    set_collision_layer_value(4, true)
    #print("hi hi")
    
func sleep():
    texture_rect.texture = ESCAPE_BLOCK_SLEEP
    modulate.a = 0.5
    set_collision_layer_value(1, false)
    set_collision_layer_value(2, false)
    set_collision_layer_value(3, false)
    set_collision_layer_value(4, false)
    #print("bye bye")
    
func flip():
    if GameManager.panic:
        if reverse:
            wake()
        else:
            sleep()
    else:
        if reverse:
            sleep()
        else:
            wake()

# Called when the node enters the scene tree for the first time.
func _ready():
    texture_rect.visible = true
    texture_rect.size.x = collision_shape.shape.size.x
    texture_rect.size.y = collision_shape.shape.size.y

func _process(delta):
    texture_rect.visible = true
    texture_rect.size.x = collision_shape.shape.size.x
    texture_rect.size.y = collision_shape.shape.size.y

    if GameManager.panic:
        if reverse:
            wake()
        else:
            sleep()
    else:
        if reverse:
            sleep()
        else:
            wake()

(It took me a few minutes to trim out a lotta unused code LMAO)
The textures load! Another issue solved.

I would mark this as the answer but I have to wait until tomorrow for whatever reason

The Stack Overflow community decided that 15 minutes is the minimum amount of time it would take to receive a healthy number of submissions and actually read/test/think about the answers provided. If you're interested you can read more about on this SO Meta Q/A. I'm not sure if it's also/still 15 minutes here on GDSE, but the rationale is basically the same.

I think there is as well a different timer for self answered questions
